# Usage of "long time no see/hear" in informal speech

Tags: idioms, spoken-english, formality

What is the most common thing to say when we send a text to someone who hasn't texted us for a few days? "**long time no see**" or "**long time no hear**" or can both be used?

Does it differ when it comes to informal but face to face situations (*unlike texting*) or can those two phrases still be used interchangeably as well?

Thanks!

Comment: "Long time no see" is a jokey expression, imitating broken English, dating back to long before the invention of texting. No doubt in a non-face to face situation most people would understand "long time no hear" as being derived from the original phrase.

Comment: Thank you for the response Kate!
Is it wrong to say "long time no see"? I have seen this phrase being used in English movies and TV more than "long time no hear". 
May I also know which is the most common to be used in day-to-day life?

Comment: As I said, "Long time no see" is the _original_ version, which is why you have heard it much more often.

Answer (score 1):

These clichés are useful in face-to-face conversations.  I'd try not to use them in written text, even informal written text like text-messages.

This particular phrase is ungrammatical, because it was borrowed from Chinese pidgin English (and is a passable word-for-word translation of Chinese 好久不见).

I'd prefer to use normal English like "I haven't heard from you since university!" or "It's been a long time (hasn't it?)"

Even in speech, in which it might get some non-ironic use, it would often be better to "just use English".

Eric Partrige in his dictionary writes ([quoted here](https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/13/messages/551.html))

> Nevertheless, this is one of the most widely used of all [Chinese phrases], *despite the fact that many of us find it tiresome*.

Comment: Thank you for attributing *Long time* to essentially a slur on foreigners who speak their language well and ours less so. Darn clever.

Comment: Thank you James ! I understand. However, is the usage of long time no see incorrect/uncommon in the context of texting? Or is it still acceptable?(even though it's better to avoid those phrases as a whole).